# Installing SQLServer 2005 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2005

It's 3 days I'm trying to install SqlServer 2005 under Windows 7 64 bit on my computer.
First let me tell you what I've done and what I've got till now .

**1**-I Installed Windows 7 64 Bit on my computer 
**2**-I tried to install SQl Server 2005 "Developer Edition"  
**2.1** But in **"System Configuration Check"** Page i recieved 2 warning , One for **"IIS Feature Requirement"** and another for **"ASP.NET Version Registration Rquired"** .
**2.1.1** . I installed **"Internet Information Services"** from "Turn Windows features on or off" section in control panel 
**2.1.2** I Enabled reporting service 32 bit from **"Inetpub=> AdminScripts => adsutil.vbs"**
**2.2** At this stage There was no waring in System Configuration Check

**3**- So I installed SQl Server 2005 Developer Edition By all default settings
**4**- I installed Sql Server 2005 Service Pack 3 64 bit

Now when when i run "Management Studio" There is no name in "Server name" section . I typed my Computer name Or "." and i got this Error :

> A network -related
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishinga connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. **(Provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider , error :40 - Could not open
>   a connection to SQL Server ) (
>   Microsoft SQL Server , Error :2)** .

I googled some for this Error and some people said follow this instruction:

> Start>sql server 2005>Configuration
>   tools>Sql Server Surface Configuration
>   Area>Surface Area Configuration for
>   services and Connections

But i got this Error :

> No SQl SErver 2005 Components were
>   found on the specified computer .
>   Either no components are installed ,
>   or you are not a administrator on this
>   computer (SQLSAC)

I'm really tired because of that , and i don't know what's wrong with this .

Some more information :
I have no additonal software on my computer , like Antivirus or Proxy 
I tried all step with "Standard Edition" either , but no difference
My user is Administrator

I tried more than 5 times all those steps including re-installing Windows 7 . 
Please help me , I'm losing all my hair

Comment: You should ask sys admin related questions on ServerFault.com, not here.

Comment: @Oded : Dear friend , I'm installing all those on my Personal laptop , Should i ask there ?

Comment: @Mostafa - There or at SuperUser.com. The question will get migrated to one of these soon, once 5 close votes go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple.

please relax for some time and read the below links once. and start again.

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/sql-server-2005/sql-server-2005-installation.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144278(SQL.90).aspx

SQL Server 2005 is supported on Windows 7 in the same manner as Windows Vista, but SQL Server 2005 SP3 is required.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I see as potential issues:

- 2005 is only supported on Win7/Server 2008 if MSSQL is SP2 or later.
- Try using TCP/IP instead of named pipes.  Named pipes is notorious for connection issues...

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem. I also installed service pack 3. Nothing worked. So I uninstalled sql server 2005, on Windows 7, and then re-installed it. I then installed Service pack 2 instead of 3 : SQLServer2005SP2-KB921896-x86-ENU.exe

Notice that I had to install the x86 version. So this is what worked for me.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=d07219b2-1e23-49c8-8f0c-63fa18f26d3a&displaylang=en